# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE not working as expected

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to isolate my database so that if I have multiple servers that read from the same DB, they do not read or update the data from same row. To do so, I have made my query look somewhat like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bridge_transaction_state as bridge WHERE bridge.state IN ('TRANSFER_SUCCESS') FOR UPDATE;
```

If I execute this query in my mysql console,

```
START TRANSACTION; 
SELECT * FROM bridge_transaction_state as bridge WHERE bridge.state IN ('TRANSFER_SUCCESS') FOR UPDATE;
```

it locks this row so that if other server tries to read the same row, it waits until the running server `COMMIT;`.

Here is the problem: if I execute same query in my NestJs code, locking does not work.

```
// update-crawler.service.ts
async updateState() {
    const queryRunner = getConnection().createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    const updateStateJobs = await this.bridgeTransactionStateRepository.getUpdateCrawlingJob();
    for (const updateStateJob of updateStateJobs) {
      await this.bridgeTransactionStateRepository.updateState(txId, nextState);
    }
    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
  }
```

```
// bridge-transaction-state.repository.ts
async getUpdateCrawlingJob(): Promise<UpdateStateJobVo[]> {
    const updateStateJobList: UpdateStateJobVo[] = await this.query(
      `SELECT * FROM bridge_transaction_state as bridge WHERE bridge.state IN ('TRANSFER_SUCCESS') FOR UPDATE;`,
    );
    return updateStateJobList;
}
```

I have run `startTransaction()` from my service, then query from repository, and `commit()` from service.
I expect this to lock the row I am locking with my query, so that no other services can read nor write before the server that is locking ends its chore and commits.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or missing?

Thanks for your time, in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what I have doing wrong.. Hoping that someone like me might be searching for answers, I'll leave my answer.

```
// update-crawler.service.ts
async updateState() {
    const queryRunner = getConnection().createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    const updateStateJobs = await this.bridgeTransactionStateRepository.getUpdateCrawlingJob();
    for (const updateStateJob of updateStateJobs) {
        await this.bridgeTransactionStateRepository.updateState(txId, nextState);
    }
    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
  }
```

I have made my queryRunner here at my service, but then,

```
// bridge-transaction-state.repository.ts
async getUpdateCrawlingJob(): Promise<UpdateStateJobVo[]> {
    const updateStateJobList: UpdateStateJobVo[] = await this.query(
      `SELECT * FROM bridge_transaction_state as bridge WHERE bridge.state IN ('TRANSFER_SUCCESS') FOR UPDATE;`,
    );
    return updateStateJobList;
}
```

where I wanted to lock was in my repository, which I did not use the queryRunner that I have made in my service.

So the solution:

```
// update-crawler.service.ts
async updateState() {
    const queryRunner = getConnection().createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    const updateStateJobs = await this.bridgeTransactionStateRepository.getUpdateCrawlingJob(queryRunner);
    for (const updateStateJob of updateStateJobs) {
        await this.bridgeTransactionStateRepository.updateState(txId, nextState);
    }
    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
  }
```

```
// bridge-transaction-state.repository.ts
async getUpdateCrawlingJob(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<UpdateStateJobVo[]> {
    const updateStateJobList: UpdateStateJobVo[] = await queryRunner.query(
      `SELECT * FROM bridge_transaction_state as bridge WHERE bridge.state IN ('TRANSFER_SUCCESS') FOR UPDATE;`,
    );
    return updateStateJobList;
}
```

I have passed the queryRunner from service to repository, and by using the same queryRunner this made my code work as expected!

Hope this helps for those who are having similar problems with me :)